# Strip all trailing whitespace except last new line

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a string:

```
var str = 'I am a \nmultiline   \nString.\n'
```

How can I replace all trailing whitespace characters with `''`, except for the last `\n`?

I have tried:

```
str.replace(/\s+$/gm, '')
```

But that returns

```
"I am a\nmultiline\nString."
```

and I would like to have something like

```
"I am a\nmultiline\nString.\n"
```

Comment: Will it always have a newline at the end? If it doesn't have a newline, do you want to add one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` matches newline characters also. So i suggest you to use the below.

```
str.replace(/[ \t]+$/gm, "")
```

OR

```
str.replace(/(?:(?![\r\n])\s)+$/gm, "")
```

`m` multiline modifier is must when your regex uses anchors. The above regex matches any kind of one or more space characters at the last but not of newline character or carriage return character.

Example:

```
> var str = 'I am a \nmultiline   \nString.\n';
undefined
> str.replace(/[ \t]+$/gm, "")
'I am a\nmultiline\nString.\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to remove all whitespace characters except `\n`, not just ` ` and `\t`, I used my answer (see above).

Comment: I'm picking this as the right answer as @hwnd's answer, although short, does not work (see my comments). Even with an added group it's similar enough to this answer, which is slightly better as it uses a cleaner non-capturing group.

Comment: Small correction: the m flag is multiline, not multiplier. Instead of having ^ and $ mean the beginning and end of the string, it means beginning and end of the line.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes it's a typo.. Thanks..'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a variant of @AvinashRaj's answer, as I want to remove all whitespace (again, except for `\n`), not just `\t` and :

```
str.replace(/[ \f\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]+$/gm, '')
```

(From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions))